# Styling textbox text

Tags: css, textbox, formatting

Here is what I want to do:

I have a disabled textbox that gets populated, ';' delimited, by filling in some other textboxes.  The values appear in the disabled box with this format:

> [Abbreviation] [value]; [Abbreviation] [value]; [Abbreviation] [value]
>   ...etc

A requirement of my project is to make the [value] bold so that it looks like this:

> [Abbreviation] **[value]**; [Abbreviation] **[value]**; [Abbreviation] **[value]**
>   ...etc

I haven't had a lot of luck with CSS or doing research to see if this is even possible.  Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: You have to use a textfield or another box that allows formatting because the standard HTML textbox does not support formatting. You can change the text font, size and color but cannot apply different formatting to different portions of a text within the textbox. I don't know how to fix your problem off the top of my head but I just know that you can't do this with a textbox. I'm sure the experts have a better solution than what I would come up with.

Comment: i'm with @Ozbekov - styling text within a text field is impossible i think. can't you work with a hidden field that gets populated, and a regular div that's styled as if it were a disabled text field?

Comment: You can style the overall text, just not portions of it.

Comment: I'm going to change the main input to a div and then I'll know that it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can format the text in a text box but you can't format partial text it's all or nothing so you could do

[Abbreviation] [value]; [Abbreviation] [value]; [Abbreviation] [value] ...etc

or

**[Abbreviation] [value]; [Abbreviation] [value]; [Abbreviation] [value] ...etc**

but not

[Abbreviation] **[value]**; [Abbreviation] **[value]**; [Abbreviation] **[value]** ...etc